# If statements in udev rules

Tags: linux, usb, rules, udev

Is it possible to make statements in udev rules via if, else or case?

I imagine something like:

```
if [ $HOSTNAME == "host1" ]
then
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="04a9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", MODE="0660", GOTO="local_usb_end"
fi
```

I did not find anything like that but maybe you can help me with that.